# Sizing div to fit a child span

Tags: html, css

Sorry if everyone has already seen this over and over, I'm sure I've done it before but can't remember or find how!

I've got a parent div tag containing a series of span tags to position a series of elements in line with each other - to clarify, the 'in line' is critical and this is just a single row, multiple sequential rows are a requirement. Using position:relative or block level elements forces it onto a new line, which isn't any use. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Positioning testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="position: relative; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;
                background-color: Fuchsia;">
        Hello world
        <span style="position:relative; left: 80px;">
            <input type="text" id="Test"/>
        </span>
        <span style="position: absolute; top: 2px; left: 350px; width:250px;
                     background-color:Lime;">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin at
          fermentum risus. Nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
          consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque mattis venenatis enim vitae 
          molestie. Integer in consequat metus. </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I promise those colours are just for testing to make things show up (and ditto the inline styling I promise) :-)

Unfortunately, the fuschia box won't size to fit around the lime. Ugly with one line, a major problem when you need two of these in sequence.

I've tried setting overflow on the parent div, which just hides all but the first line of the span. I've tried setting elements to clear in all sorts of places but none had any visible effect.

Could anyone tell me what I'm missing please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Positioning testing</title>

        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            #container {
                position: relative; 
                padding-top: 2px; 
                padding-bottom: 2px; 
                background-color: Fuchsia;
                float:left;
                width: 100%;
            }

            #container > span {
                float:left;
            }

            #greenbox {
                width: 250px;
                background-color:Lime;
            }

        </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <span id="helloworld">Hello world</span>
        <span id="inputbox">
            <input type="text" id="Test"/>
        </span>
        <span id="greenbox">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin at
          fermentum risus. Nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
          consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque mattis venenatis enim vitae 
          molestie. Integer in consequat metus. </span>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; background-color: Fuchsia;">
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;">Hello world,/div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;">
        <input type="text" id="Test"/>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width:250px; background-color:Lime;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin at
      fermentum risus. Nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
      consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque mattis venenatis enim vitae 
      molestie. Integer in consequat metus.
    </div>
</div>
```

Change the margins and widths as necessary

Comment: Puts the Hello World on one line and the rest on the next, sorry :-(

Comment: You want all 3 on the same line?

Comment: Yes, they all need to be in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Because the lime box is `position: absolute`, it is completely ignored when performing the layout.  Therefore, the fuchsia box is sized as though the lime box didn't exist.

You need to change the fuchsia box to `position: relative` to make included in the layout logic, and add `display: block` to force its width.  (Although it would be better to change it to a `<div>`, which already is `display: block`)

Comment: If I set the lime box to relative and block (or same as a div) it forces it onto a new line rather than aligning with the previous content on the page though. I could do a negative top offset but that's encoding a dependency on the font and creating a maintenance headache.

Answer (score 0):

your "Lime" SPAN is absolutely positioned, so it is taken out of the page flow.

Try using float: left; instead.

Comment: If I do that it ignores the left position and forces it fully to the left of the content, before the previous elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the SPAN to display as a block element and position it relative to the container.  It's the absolute positioning of the span that causes it to be removed from the rendering order and keeps the container from resizing around it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
    <title>Positioning testing</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div style="position: relative; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; 
                background-color: Fuchsia;"> 
        Hello world 
        <span style="position:relative; left: 80px;"> 
            <input type="text" id="Test"/> 
        </span> 
        <span style="margin-top: 2px; margin-left: 350px; width:250px; 
                     background-color:Lime; display: block;"> 
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin at 
          fermentum risus. Nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  
          consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque mattis venenatis enim vitae  
          molestie. Integer in consequat metus. </span> 
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Oh, and by the way, I hope you're going to do this with stylesheets and classes once you get it nailed down.  Also, you may need to give it a negative top margin to move it up relative to the top of the container.

Comment: I won't put attributes direct in the tags live, that's just for quick testing. The problem with that method is it forces the lime span onto a new line, rather than aligning it with the top of the fuschia div.

Comment: See my note about giving it a negative top margin -- or you could put all of the preceding text inside the previous span and float that span left.  Both accomplish the same basic purpose.

Comment: Negative top margin encodes a font dependency, which I'm keen to avoid. Putting the previous content into a span and floating that left works in IE7 but causes Firefox and Chrome to render the Fuschia div as just a stripe and breaks down completely when a second row is introduced.

Comment: You could make the top margin in `em` units not in `px` to make it relative to the font -- say `-1.2em`.  I'm not sure why floating the first span left would cause the outer DIV to not render around the lime green span if you've removed its absolute positioning.  It should size to fit any child elements providing you haven't removed them from the rendering flow (by floating or absolute positioning).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need is the fuchsia div to be "display: inline" to wrap around the inner content. ¿isn't that?

Comment: If you mean setting the fuschia div to:

    <div style="display:inline; position: relative; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; background-color: Fuchsia; width:700px;">

No, that doesn't work.